# What's the difference between loop.create_task, asyncio.async/ensure_future and Task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine, python-asyncio

I'm a little bit confused by some `asyncio` functions. I see there is [`BaseEventLoop.create_task(coro)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.create_task) function to schedule a co-routine. The documentation for `create_task` says its a new function and for compatibility we should use [`asyncio.async(coro)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.async) which by referring to docs again I see is an alias for [`asyncio.ensure_future(coro)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) which again schedules the execution of a co-routine.

Meanwhile, I've been using [`Task(coro)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) for scheduling co-routine execution and that too seems to be working fine. so, what's the difference between all these?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As you've noticed, they all do the same thing.

`asyncio.async` had to be replaced with `asyncio.ensure_future` because in Python >= 3.5, `async` has been made a keyword[[1]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#backwards-compatibility).

`create_task`'s raison d'etre[[2]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.create_task):

> Third-party event loops can use their own subclass of Task for interoperability. In this case, the result type is a subclass of Task.

And this also means you **should not** create a `Task` directly, because different event loops might have different ways of creating a "Task".

**Edit**

Another *important* difference is that in addition to accepting coroutines, `ensure_future` also accepts any awaitable object; `create_task` on the other hand just accepts coroutines.

Comment: Sounds like I'd better use `ensure_future` then. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: Unless you're writing code for Python < 3.4.4, of course ;)

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't pay attention! I _am_ using Python < 3.4.4 as it happens; 3.4.3 to be precise.

Comment: This was counter-intuitive because it sounded like you said to use ensure_future and not create_task, so I made my research. In 2016, [Guido said the opposite](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555). If you know you have a coroutine and you want to schedule its execution, you should just call create_task directly. create_task exists so a third party loop can return a subclass so you shouldn't call the task constructor directly. Hope that clears things up for other asyncio neophytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Future

A `Future` is an object that is supposed to have a result in the future.

Or more officially:

A `Future` is an `awaitable` object that represents an eventual result of an asynchronous operation.

> Object is `awaitable` if it can be used in an `await` expression.

So, any `Future` can be `await`'ed.

## Task

[Docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task)

> `Tasks` are used to schedule coroutines concurrently.
>
> When a coroutine is wrapped into a `Task` with functions like
> `asyncio.create_task()` the coroutine is automatically scheduled to run
> soon.

**A Task actually is a Future:**

> A `Future`-like object that runs a Python coroutine.

`Task` is subclass of a `Future`.

> `asyncio.Task`inherits from `Future` all of its APIs except
> `Future.set_result()` and `Future.set_exception()`.

## create_task(coro)

[Docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks)

> Wraps the `coro` coroutine into a `Task` and schedules its execution.
> Returns the `Task` object.

## asyncio.ensure_future(obj, ...)

It actually ensures that `obj` is a `Future`. If it's not it creates a `Task` from `obj`. That's it.

## Some conclusions

- If `obj` already is a `Future`, `ensure_future` will return the same `obj`. In this case return value of a function **may be a Future and not a Task** - since `Task` is just a subclass of a `Future`.
- With `ensure_future` you **CAN** do this:

```py
# will create a Task
task = asyncio.ensure_future(coroutine())
# will ensure that it is a Task
task = asyncio.ensure_future(task)
```

or this:

```
# will create a Task
task = asyncio.create_task(coroutine())
# will ensure that it is a Task
task = asyncio.ensure_future(task)
```

So, you can call `ensure_future` on a `Task`.
But you **CAN'T** do the same with `create_task`:

```
# will create a Task
task = asyncio.create_task(coroutine())
# will raise an exception
task = asyncio.create_task(task)
```

> TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got Task

## Pay attention

[According to docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future)

> `create_task()` is the preferred way for creating new `Tasks`.

> Deprecated since version 3.10: Deprecation warning is emitted if obj
> is not a Future-like object and loop is not specified and there is no
> running event loop.