# asyncio.ensure_future vs. BaseEventLoop.create_task vs. simple coroutine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, coroutine, python-asyncio

I've seen several basic Python 3.5 tutorials on asyncio doing the same operation in various flavours.
In this code:

```
import asyncio  

async def doit(i):
    print("Start %d" % i)
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("End %d" % i)
    return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    #futures = [asyncio.ensure_future(doit(i), loop=loop) for i in range(10)]
    #futures = [loop.create_task(doit(i)) for i in range(10)]
    futures = [doit(i) for i in range(10)]
    result = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*futures))
    print(result)
```

All the three variants above that define the `futures` variable achieve the same result; the only difference I can see is  that with the third variant the execution is out of order (which should not matter in most cases). Is there any other difference? Are there cases where I can't just use the simplest variant (plain list of coroutines)?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

### Actual info:

Starting from Python 3.7 `asyncio.create_task(coro)` high-level function [was added](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks) for this purpose.

You should use it instead other ways of creating tasks from coroutimes. However if you need to create task from arbitrary awaitable, you should use `asyncio.ensure_future(obj)`.

---

### Old info:

### `ensure_future` vs `create_task`

`ensure_future` is a method to create [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) from [`coroutine`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines). It creates tasks in different ways based on argument (including using of `create_task` for coroutines and future-like objects).

`create_task` is an abstract method of `AbstractEventLoop`. Different event loops can implement this function different ways.

You should use `ensure_future` to create tasks. You'll need `create_task` only if you're going to implement your own event loop type.

**Upd:**

@bj0 pointed at [Guido's answer](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477) on this topic:

> The point of `ensure_future()` is if you have something that could
>   either be a coroutine or a `Future` (the latter includes a `Task` because
>   that's a subclass of `Future`), and you want to be able to call a method
>   on it that is only defined on `Future` (probably about the only useful
>   example being `cancel()`). When it is already a `Future` (or `Task`) this
>   does nothing; when it is a coroutine it *wraps* it in a `Task`.
>
> If you know that you have a coroutine and you want it to be scheduled,
>   the correct API to use is `create_task()`. The only time when you should
>   be calling `ensure_future()` is when you are providing an API (like most
>   of asyncio's own APIs) that accepts either a coroutine or a `Future` and
>   you need to do something to it that requires you to have a `Future`.

and later:

> In the end I still believe that `ensure_future()` is an appropriately
>   obscure name for a rarely-needed piece of functionality. When creating
>   a task from a coroutine you should use the appropriately-named
>   `loop.create_task()`. Maybe there should be an alias for that
>   `asyncio.create_task()`?

It's surprising to me. My main motivation to use `ensure_future` all along was that it's higher-level function comparing to loop's member `create_task` (discussion [contains](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-269042731) some ideas like adding `asyncio.spawn` or `asyncio.create_task`).

I can also point that in my opinion it's pretty convenient to use universal function that can handle any `Awaitable` rather than coroutines only.

However, Guido's answer is clear: **"When creating a task from a coroutine you should use the appropriately-named `loop.create_task()`"**

### When coroutines should be wrapped in tasks?

Wrap coroutine in a Task - is a way to start this coroutine "in background". Here's example:

```
import asyncio


async def msg(text):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print(text)


async def long_operation():
    print('long_operation started')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('long_operation finished')


async def main():
    await msg('first')

    # Now you want to start long_operation, but you don't want to wait it finised:
    # long_operation should be started, but second msg should be printed immediately.
    # Create task to do so:
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(long_operation())

    await msg('second')

    # Now, when you want, you can await task finised:
    await task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
first
long_operation started
second
long_operation finished
```

You can replace `asyncio.ensure_future(long_operation())` with just `await long_operation()` to feel the difference.

Comment: According to Guido, you should use `create_task` if you really need a a task object, which you normally shouldn't need: https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555

Comment: @bj0 thank you for this link. I updated answer adding information from this discussion.

Comment: does `ensure_future` automatically adds the created `Task` to the main event loop?

Comment: @AlQuemist every coroutine, future or task you create is automatically binded to some event loop, where it'll be executed later. By default it is [current](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoopPolicy.get_event_loop) event loop for current thread, but you can specify other event loop using `loop` keyword argument ([see ensure_future signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future)).

Comment: why does msg() need to have an await within it? if I reverse the order of asyncio.sleep and print(text) in msg(), control stays with with long function until it sleeps.

Comment: @laycat we need `await` within `msg()` to return control to event loop on second call. Event loop once receive control will be able to start `long_operation()`. It made to demonstrate how `ensure_future` starts coroutine to execute concurrently with current execution flow.

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov thanks, your explanation fits the results I got as well. I played around with a few combinations and it was interesting. thanks!

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov, why do we need `await task` in the end? If I drop it nothing seemingly changes.

Comment: @garej if you drop it, you shouldn't see the last output `long_operation finished` because `main()` (and whole event loop) finishes earlier than `long_operation()` task. It guess it may not be the case if you run script in Jupyter, but anyway the idea of `await task` is that we need it to wait the task is finished.

Comment: not sure if this is a good question but ensure future seems to be it just creates a wrapper so your coroutine can awaited/called later? Not sure why either are needed we can't just await our coroutine directly or something like that.

Comment: @CharlieParker  it just creates a wrapper AND starts the coroutine execution, while we can do other stuff. If we await coroutine directly, we can't do anything else until we finished with it. If we create a task, we can start some other coroutine immediately and await for the task later (it can be already finished by then).

Comment: @CharlieParker here's the more detailed answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37345564/1113207

Answer (score 55):

#### `create_task()`

- accepts coroutines,
- returns Task,
- it is invoked in context of the loop.

---

#### `ensure_future()`

- accepts Futures, coroutines, awaitable objects,
- returns Task (or Future if Future passed).
- if the given arg is a coroutine it uses `create_task`,
- loop object can be passed.

As you can see the create_task is more specific.

---

#### `async` function without create_task or ensure_future

Simple invoking `async` function returns coroutine

```
>>> async def doit(i):
...     await asyncio.sleep(3)
...     return i
>>> doit(4)   
<coroutine object doit at 0x7f91e8e80ba0>
```

And since the [`gather`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#l614) under the hood ensures (`ensure_future`) that args are futures, explicitly `ensure_future` is redundant.

Similar question [What's the difference between loop.create_task, asyncio.async/ensure_future and Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980086/whats-the-difference-between-loop-create-task-asyncio-async-ensure-future-and)

Comment: not sure if this is a good question but ensure future seems to be it just creates a wrapper so your coroutine can awaited/called later? Not sure why either are needed we can't just await our coroutine directly or something like that.

Answer (score 22):

> Note: Only valid for **Python 3.7** (for Python 3.5 refer to the [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36415477/764592)).

From the official docs:

> [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) (added in Python 3.7) is the preferable way for spawning new tasks instead of [`ensure_future()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future).

---

## Detail:

So now, in Python 3.7 onwards, there are 2 top-level wrapper function (similar but different):

- [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task): which simply call [`event_loop.create_task(coro)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) directly. ([see source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L319-L325))
- [`ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future) which also call [`event_loop.create_task(coro)`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) if it is coroutine or else it is simply to ensure the return type to be a [asyncio.Future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future). ([see source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L573-L593)). Anyway, `Task` is still a `Future` due to its class inheritance ([ref](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L55-L56)).

Well, utlimately both of these wrapper functions will help you call [`BaseEventLoop.create_task`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L387-L399). The only difference is `ensure_future` accept any [`awaitable`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__await__) object and help you convert it into a Future. And also you can provide your own `event_loop` parameter in `ensure_future`. And depending if you need those capability or not, you can simply choose which wrapper to use.

Comment: I think there is another difference that is not documented: if you try to call asyncio.create_task before running the loop, you will have a problem since asyncio.create_task is expecting a running loop. You can use asyncio.ensure_future in this case, however, since a running loop is not a requirement.

Comment: not sure if this is a good question but ensure future seems to be it just creates a wrapper so your coroutine can awaited/called later? Not sure why either are needed we can't just await our coroutine directly or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

for your example, all the three types execute asynchronously. the only difference is that, in the third example, you pre-generated all 10 coroutines, and submitted to the loop together. so only the last one gives output randomly.

Comment: not sure if this is a good question but ensure future seems to be it just creates a wrapper so your coroutine can awaited/called later? Not sure why either are needed we can't just await our coroutine directly or something like that.