# Python asyncio event loop. Run loop forever after completing an async task

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, asyncsocket

Well I'm new to async in python. I'm creating a server using the call `asyncio.start_server`, the problem is that I'm running the same loop twice, the first time to create/start the server calling the `loop.run_until_complete`, and after that `loop.run_forever`. Here the code I use.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    sv_wrapper = ServerWrapper(
        host='localhost',
        port=5003
    )

    loop.run_until_complete(sv_wrapper.create())
    print(repr(sv_wrapper.server))

    loop.run_forever()
```

([Full code example](https://github.com/MiguelLattuada/python-playground/blob/master/async/server.py))
Honestly I do not get the last call to `loop.run_forever()`, **does de created server with `asyncio.start_server` run on the same event loop that executes the call, or a new event loop is created internally?** 
 If a new event loop is created internally, I do not need the call to run forever, for example just keeping the process running could be enough (and of course having a reference to the created [Server](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.Server)).
I do not know if this have sense at all, but if the server is a loop itself (manage in/out coming connections as future tasks) Is it possible to push tasks with `loop.create_task`?
I did not come with a specific problem and sorry about that. I come from a nodejs background and I thought it would be easier to get async in python, thanks for your help, and any extras will be well received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Honestly I do not get the last call to loop.run_forever(), does de
>   created server with asyncio.start_server run on the same event loop
>   that executes the call, or a new event loop is created internally?

It's single global event loop. Usually end-user manages creating and running event loops, libraries don't do it internally.

> If a new event loop is created internally, I do not need the call to
>   run forever, for example just keeping the process running could be
>   enough (and of course having a reference to the created Server).

I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but here some thoughts:

1. Your server can work only while event loop is running. Server can recieve or send something only via event loop.
2. `loop.run_until_complete(sv_wrapper.create())` means that event
   loop used to execute one job (to create server) and then being stopped.
   Again it means you should run it to make created server work.

> I do not know if this have sense at all, but if the server is a loop
>   itself (manage in/out coming connections as future tasks) Is it
>   possible to push tasks with loop.create_task?

Server is not an event loop itself. Roughly saying, server is one of async tasks managed by global event loop.

You can create other async tasks ([better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36415477/1113207) to do it with `ensure_future`) that will be managed by same global event loop (and through that being run concurrently with server).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check the source code?

```
try:
    events._set_running_loop(self)
    while True:                   # Here is the point.
        self._run_once()          # Run event loop once.
        if self._stopping:        # Check stop
            break                 # Stop event loop.
finally:
    self._stopping = False
    self._thread_id = None
    events._set_running_loop(None)
    self._set_coroutine_wrapper(False)
    if self._asyncgens is not None:
        sys.set_asyncgen_hooks(*old_agen_hooks)
```

This is part of `run_forever`. You can see, without call `run_forever`, you will not even run any task.