# Data reception over web-socket in a non-blocking way

Tags: python, sockets, subscription, coroutine, preemptive

I am trying to store the data received over socket while executing other functions simultaneously.

The way the code works is that it [waits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) to receive a data over socket. If I want to receive the next data frame, I need to call `recv()` again which basically means that my program will stop at socket code and can not move ahead.

Is there a way to receive the data and execute other lines of code simultaneously?

Comment: Threading module? Asyncio? https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html

Comment: It is already built upon asyncio https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/design.html

Comment: @Ehsan: Is your code basically a `while` loop where you `await` a `recv` call? What do you mean by "can not move ahead"?

Comment: I am trying to think of it as hardware module in microcontroller like a timer which is working independently while CPU is executing other stuff and when the timer needs an attention, it raises an interrupt and then CPU handles the interrupt request and then goes back to where it already left. I wonder if I can have the same procedure for the web-socket data reception?

Comment: @Blender: I mean if I want to receive like 10 packets of data I should create a loop which exceutes the recv() 10 times:   
       for i in range (0,10):
            greeting = await websocket.recv()
            print ('\n')
            print("i = {} \n < {}".format(i, greeting))
            i = i + 1

Comment: @Ehsan: Without more concrete information about what you're actually trying to do it's hard to give you a useful answer. You can push the execution of a task into the "background" by using `asyncio.ensure_future(task())`, which would allow you to execute code in response to your data packets without waiting for it to complete.

Comment: @Blender: Suppose that in the following example, the `long_operation` takes 100 minutes, does it mean the `task =... `goes to background and after 100 minutes the `await msg('second')`  is executed? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342899/asyncio-ensure-future-vs-baseeventloop-create-task-vs-simple-coroutine)

Comment: @Blender: I am trying to receive streaming data with web-sockets over several subscriptions given that the code execution does not suspend in each web-socket program and data reception goes into background while I can execute other lines of the code in the program.

Comment: The easiest way is using a [thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread). (Notice I said easiest, but not most efficient)

Comment: @Ehsan: no, `long_operation` is just executed concurrently to the rest of your code. Think of it like spawning a new thread. The difference is that no code is actually being executed in parallel due to `asyncio` using an event loop.

Comment: @Blender: I removed the line `await task` in the example and expected to see `long_operation finished` but it didn't happen. Why is that?

Comment: @Ehsan: `loop.run_until_complete(main())` runs until `main` is complete. Since you never wait for `task` to finish, the program ends too early.

Comment: @Blender: What should I add so that main remains running and executes everything in it like printing `long_operation` and I can execute another function at the same time, say I can execute `print('test')`.

Comment: @Ehsan: I would condense your questions about `asyncio` into a single question and ask that separately.

Comment: @Blender: That would be great, thanks!

Comment: @Blender: Also, could you please let me know when you posted the question? Thanks!

Comment: @Ehsan: I meant for you to post the question, since I'm not sure what you don't understand from the few comments you've posted on this one.

Comment: @Blender: Got it, thanks!