# AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer not handling 2nd message before 1st finished

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-channels

After moving to channels2 I'm still struggling with python's "new" async/await and asyncio.
First I tried to reproduce [Worker and Background Tasks](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/worker.html) from the docs but then I realised that my task should just run as simple `async` function.

So, my test function is

```
async def replay_run(self, event):
    print_info("replay_run", event, self.channel_name)
    import asyncio
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print_info("replay_run-",i, event, self.channel_name)
```

and both of the following calls inside `async def receive_json(self, event)`
seem to prevent a subsequent incoming message from being handled right away.

Version 1:

```
await self.channel_layer.send(
    self.channel_name, {
        "type": "replay_run", "sessionID": msg["sessionID"]
    })
```

Version 2:

```
    await self.replay_run(msg)
```

First I thought of version 1 because I thought I needed to register a "new event consumer" like `await asyncio.gather`...
Any hint on how to do this right is appreciated ...

Comment: Are you saying your `print_info` not running as expected ? Or Did you receive any error ? Also What do you mean by not handling 2nd message before 1st finished ?

Comment: No error, but I expected interleaving output of the two loops counting from 1 to 10. Instead the first counting finishes even before I see my 2nd incoming message and _then_ the 2nd counting from 1 to 10 after that

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: [django.channels async consumer does not appear to execute asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871831/django-channels-async-consumer-does-not-appear-to-execute-asynchronously)

Apparently the way would be

Version 3:

`asyncio.ensure_future( self.replay_runit(msg) )`

...  in order to schedule the "long running coroutine" without blocking the channel.