# Unable to schedule anything in asyncio. (Python 3.7.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am currently working on asyncio with python 3.7.x not sure about the exact version, right now I am trying to schedule a task. And I am unable to get an output, even when running the thing forever. Here is the code I currently have

```
import asyncio

async def print_now():
  print("Hi there")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.call_later(print_now())
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(1))
```

This gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Coding\python\async\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    loop.call_later(print_now())
TypeError: call_later() missing 1 required positional argument: 'callback'
```

The call back in `call_later()` is `print_now` I've tried just `print_now` and `print_now()`
I have also tried using `loop.run_forever()` instead of `loop.run_until_complete()` and so far I didn't get anything

Sometimes I get either no output or a different error.

Comment: Did you read the error message and [how `call_later` works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_later)…?

Comment: Look at the documentation for [call_later](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_later). You're missing a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, yes, you're missing a `delay` argument . First one is supposed to be the delay while the second one is a callback ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_later)).

```
loop.call_later(delay, callback, *args, context=None)
```

---

Second, the callback is supposed to be a function. What you're passing is `print_now()` which is gonna evaluate to `None`. You might find out that

> 'NoneType' object is not callable

So you're gonna need to pass `print_now` — without parentheses — as a callback. This way you're passing a function instead of the result of its application.

---

Third, `async` functions are supposed to be `await`ed on. Your scenario doesn't seem to need that, so just drop the `async` keyword.

> When you call an awaitable function, you create a new coroutine object. The code inside the function won't run until you then await on the function or run it as a task

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441424/learning-asyncio-coroutine-was-never-awaited-warning-error). You might want to check out

Comment: Oh can't believe I missed that part. Guess I wasn't paying attention. Thanks.

Comment: Note that, with `print_now` defined as in the question, `print_now()` won't evaluate to None, but to a fresh coroutine object. It doesn't change anything, it still won't be callable, it's just the error that will be different.