# How to stop code after replying to a message in Telegram Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Now I am sending a message to the user, and if the user sends a message with four buttons, the first one is pressed and the code does not stop working (it waits for a message from the user further). How can I make the code stop after clicking on the first button?

```
import random
from telethon import TelegramClient, events


api_id = 109258102341
api_hash = 'k12iy5k2u43v51ui34'

client = TelegramClient('waererfer', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=('@username')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    if event.message.button_count == 4:
        await event.message.click(0)

client.start()

client.send_message('@username', 'Hello')
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: By "stop working", do you mean "stop reacting to the message" or entirely exit the program?

Comment: @Lonami exit the program

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

You should use:

```
await client.disconnect()
```

And the script will exit after sending the message.

Comment: Compiler says that that I should put this line with await in async method, so I put it in method `normal_handler(event)`. Code starts working it asks phone number, password but then the error apperars `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MessageMethods.send_message' was never awaited
  client.send_message('@username', 'Hello')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: Actually, it should be fine to just use `client.disconnect()` without `await`.

Comment: You need to keep `client.run_until_disconnected()`, but use `await client.disconnect()` when you want the first call to exit (as the client will be disconnected). That is, you want to disconnect inside the handler after `click`.

Comment: @Lonami thank you but error still appears: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MessageMethods.send_message' was never awaited   client.send_message('@username', 'Hello') RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441424/learning-asyncio-coroutine-was-never-awaited-warning-error