# How can I call an async function inside a command in discord python?

Tags: python, function, asynchronous, discord

For example:

```
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
   await ctx.send('hello')
   facts()

async def facts(ctx):
   await ctx.send('facts')
```

I tried this but it usually gives an error like - RunTimeWarning: 'coroutine _____ was never awaited'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning asyncio: "coroutine was never awaited" warning error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441424/learning-asyncio-coroutine-was-never-awaited-warning-error)

Comment: Please, in the future, you can search your error through google and typically find a good solution on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is to add an `await.` before your async function.

```py
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
   await ctx.send('hello')
   await facts(ctx)

async def facts(ctx):
   await ctx.send('facts')
```

And there you'd be able to call your async function.

Comment: Please flag a question as a duplicate instead of answering it.