# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.get_me' was never awaited

Tags: python, warnings, telethon

So I am learning the telethon library for Pythonm but right in the beggining I've ran into the error:

```
    /Users/user1/Desktop/TelegramBot/main.py:8: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.get_me' was never awaited
  print(client.get_me())
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Running  the following code:

```
import decouple
from telethon import TelegramClient


client = TelegramClient('testSesh', decouple.config('API_ID_TEST'), decouple.config('API_HASH_TEST'))
client.start()

print(client.get_me())
```

I have read the basic documentation for this module but I wasn't able to find the correct solution. Please, guys, help me :/

Thank you.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441424/learning-asyncio-coroutine-was-never-awaited-warning-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `await`:

```py
import decouple
from telethon import TelegramClient

client = TelegramClient('testSesh', decouple.config('API_ID_TEST'), decouple.config('API_HASH_TEST'))

async def main():
    await client.start()
    print(await client.get_me())

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

`start()` is special-cased in v1 to not need the `await` but it's generally better if you write all your code inside an `async def` and not rely on this magic.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for your advice! It indeed has worked out for me, and seemingly, all I need now is to brush up on some async coding.