# python telebot multithreading

Tags: python, bots, telebot

I need to create a program to run multiple bots via telebot. How to remove this error?

## code

```
def start_bot(*args):
    token = a.bot_token.split()[0]
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    async def start_fun(message):
        bot.send_message( message.chat.id, 'message', parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=webAppKeyboard())
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

## ERROR

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py:100: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'start_bot.<locals>.start_fun' was never awaited
  task(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

For more more info [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441424/learning-asyncio-coroutine-was-never-awaited-warning-error)

Comment: I don't understand how to implement this into my code

Comment: I forgot to specify how I run the function

Comment: `threading.Thread(target=start_bot, args=(a.bot_token)).start()`